# How to perform a tree search on a connect-4 board and identify the best move?

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I need to create a recursive function that iterates through all possible moves of a "4-in-a-row" game at a given depth and finds the best move.

The functions available are:

```
eval_pos(board, pid) # Returns eval score of a given board and pid(player id, either -1 or 1) 
get_legal_moves(board) # Returns all legal moves in a tuple
```

The goal is to create a recursive function which finds what move gives the best score, given the best play from both parts.

```
def get_score(board, depth, pid):
    moves = get_legal_moves(board)
    evals = []
    for move in moves:
        board[move] = pid
        evals.append(eval_pos(board, pid))
        board[move] = 0 #0 signifies an empty board space, doing this to prevent filling the board

    if depth == 0:
        return max(evals)

    idx = evals.index(max(evals))
    board[moves[idx]] = pid
    # Notice we are passing -pid on each new iteration
    return get_score(board, depth-1, -pid, start_pid)
```

What I've come up with so far, does not work at all. It essentially does what I want in *reverse* and skipping a lot of positions, where it checks the best move for player1 in the first position, then the best move for player2 in the following position and so on. However, it needs to search through ALL the moves and then determine what is best given the best counterplay. Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds like you want to write a [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) algorithm, correct?

Comment: Had too google the term, but yes that seems correct!

Comment: OK. I'd pull up resources/pseudocode and try to implement it. The current code is a good attempt but not that close to depth-limited MM. A lot of examples will use tic tac toe, but it doesn't change the algorithm. When you hit a terminal node you have a definite outcome win/lose/draw, otherwise if your depth runs out, call your heuristic on the board. Minimax captures the "given the best counterplay" aspect automatically. You also ask about efficiency--look into alpha-beta pruning once you get the basic algorithm working.

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work, however it is extremely slow and can only reach a depth of 5 before it becomes unusable.

```
def minimax(board, depth, max_turn):
    # Base case
    if depth == 0:
        return eval_pos(board)

    eval = eval_pos(board)

    if eval is None:
        return 0

    if abs(eval) == 100:
        return eval

    moves = get_legal_moves(board)

    if max_turn:
        return max([minimax(update_board(board, move, 1), depth-1, False) for move in moves])
    else:
        return min([minimax(update_board(board, move, -1), depth-1, True) for move in moves])
```